# How to add email template containing embed html code in meteor project

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars, meteor-helper

I am new to meteor js. Could you please suggest me how to add email template containing embed html code in meteor project. I had tried few packages,but its not working.Could you please explain with a sample example.

Note: When a user register into my site. Both of us (new user and me) have to get the email. Both contains different embed html content.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic example assuming you use blaze:

In your template events:

```
var email = emailAddress; //define emailAddress
var dataContext = {
    yourname: getDataFromSomewhere; //whatever you define in dataContext is used in email template
};
var html = Blaze.toHTMLWithData(Template.mailTemplateName, dataContext);
Meteor.call('sendMail', yourname, email, html);
```

Mail template:

```
<template name="mailTemplateName">
    <h3>Hello {{yourname}}</h3>
</template>
```

Inside your methods:

```
sendMail: function(yourname, email, html) {
    this.unblock();
    var options = {
      from:"from@from.com",
      to: email,
      subject: 'Mail subject field',
      html: html
    };
    Email.send(options)
}
```

You only need email package (`meteor add email` in console or add `email` to your packages) and configure SMTP for this to work. Documentation for email package and usage [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/email)

SMTP configuration example (in server!)

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    smtp = {
    username: 'someMail@something.com',
    password: 'password here',  
    server:   'server.something.com',
    port: 25 //change with correct port
}

process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.username) + ':' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.password) + '@' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.server) //+ ':' + smtp.port;
});
```

If you get whats going on in this code, you can easily play with it and send different emails with different data using different html templates

Answer (score 0):

I luckily implemented this requirement yesterday. So below is the direction to send HTML using email package.

execute command;

> **meteor add email**
>
> **meteor add meteorhacks:ssr**

Create an HTML which will be accessible by **SERVER**.

below is the sample code for HTML at PROJECT/**email.html** to add email package

```
<template name="email">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td width="600">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <td>{{name}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Age</th>
        <td>{{age}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</template>
```

In **SERVER/main.js** file you need to import the package using,

```
import { Email } from 'meteor/email';

Meteor.startup(() => {

  //fill EMAIL_ID, PASSWORD
  process.env.MAIL_URL = "smtp://EMAIL_ID:PASSWORD@smtp.gmail.com:465";

  SSR.compileTemplate( 'htmlEmail', Assets.getText( 'email.html' ) );

    var emailData = {
      name: "Jishnu S",
      age: "25"       
    };

  Email.send({
      to: "abc@gmail.com",
      from: "email_ID",
      subject: "Example Email",
      html: SSR.render( 'htmlEmail', emailData )
    });
});
```

above code is for gmail SMTP configuration enabled emailing.
check email and Voila..!!!! it works. Enjoy! Happy coding!

Comment: Hi ! I've test your code, but i've "Error: Cannot find module './email.html' on my console :( The relative path is correct

Comment: what is your directory structure?